# Passing XML from XSLT to C# function

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I got an XSLT variable `resultxml` which holds a complete xml. Now I want to save this XML in to a xml File.

I had written some code like this
In XSLT

```
  <xsl:value-of select="XSLTHelper:SaveXML($resultxml)"/>
```

In C#

```
public static void SaveXML(string xmls)
{
    File.WriteAllText( HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/missing_data.xml"), xmls.ToString());
}
```

Data saves correctly but not in XML format just a string value. Is there is any way that I can maintain my XML structure and save it in File?

Comment: Did you try to use XmlDocument::Save. For example see [msdn: XmlDocument.Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @hr_117 I can't use this as I am getting plain string at "xmls".first I need is to get correct xml in my function "SaveXML" so that I can save it

Comment: Please show us exactly where and how you define and initialize the variable `$resultxml`, we need to know its type and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you pass in some nodes from XSLT and not a string you might want to try whether using

```
public static void SaveXML(XPathNodeIterator nodes)
{
  foreach (XPathNavigator node in nodes)
  {
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/missing_data.xml")))
    {
       node.WriteSubtree(xw);
    }
  }
}
```

instead of `public static void SaveXML(string xmls)` gives you the result you want. Of course the code I posted that writes to a single file is kind of nonsense if you really passed in several nodes to your function, but assuming you pass in a single node it should write that to the file `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/missing_data.xml")`.